# Не получается сделать прыжок врага в 2D Платформере на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как я понял, проблема в том, что враг преследует игрока по осям x и у (y стоит на 0) и из-за этого враг не прыгает когда достигает возвышения, но не знаю как решить.
вот скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour 
{

public int health = 20;
public int damage = 10;

Animator anim;

public Transform player;
Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed;
public float agroDistance;
public float jumpForce;

public void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    health -= damage;

    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Die();
    }
}

public void Die()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

private void Update()
{
    float distToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);      

    if (distToPlayer < agroDistance)
    {
        StartHunting();
    }
    else
    {
        StopHunting();
    }
}

void StartHunting()
{
        anim.SetBool("isWalking", true);

    if (player.position.x < transform.position.x)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(3, 3); 
    }
    else if (player.position.x > transform.position.x)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        transform.localScale = new Vector2(-3, 3);
    }
}

void StopHunting()
{
    anim.SetBool("isWalking", false);
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
}

void Jump()
{
    Debug.Log("adasd");
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        Jump();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Я думаю лучше всего этот вопрос решать через Рейкаст - стрелять лучом и врага вперед и анализировать расстояние до возвышений, ну и прыгать)

Comment: Я думал об этом, но это не решает проблемы - враг не может прыгать из-за того что преследует игрока по координатам x и y, а y = 0, из-за этого он не может менять координату y

Comment: Ну так добавьте в метод StartHunting условие наличия препятствия перед врагом, и если оно есть - поднимайте y, а если нет, то блокируйте в 0